# Trying to find fantasy book about teen girl who is taking care of a little boy from an alternate/overlapping world. May have been a YA novel

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, parallel-universe

I am trying to find the name of a fantasy novel I read as a teenager. It was about a little boy, around 4 or 5, from another dimension who is hidden in the main character's dimension to protect him. The main character is a teen girl whose mom takes in foster kids and stray animals. The little boy shows up in old fashioned clothes with an oddly worded note asking for him to be cared for. He has a teardrop earring on one ear that he won't let anyone touch. He has lavender eyes. He is also mute.

The girl steps into the role as main caregiver (her mom works alot I think). She and the boy form a bond and he seems to take on characteristics of foster children she had grown close to in the past. I think he also forms a bond with a stray cat the family had taken in.

The little boy loves music and on an outing they meet a guy playing a penny whistle. The little boy stops to listen in almost a trance like state. The guy befriends them. He drives an old beat up van. At some point the guy buys the little boy a whistle of his own.

The girl sometimes sees visions of the little boy's world, that seem to shimmer but otherwise look real and overlap the scenery in her world.
There is a wizard or sorcerer that is making attempts to find the boy by looking through mirrors. He eventually finds him by looking through the girl's mirror.

The earring that boy wears causes him to be a sort of changeling, which is why he takes in characteristics of others.

The sorcerer momentarily turns the girl against the boy. I remember terminology similar to "he placed a splinter of ice in her heart". Since her love of the boy was protecting him, the sorcerer is able to break into that dimension and kidnap the boy.

The girl snaps out of her spell and she and the guy drive in his van to find the boy. They end up in a multi-level parking garage that they have figured out is a doorway to the other dimension. There is a showdown between the little boy's family and the sorcerer. At some point the girl pulls the earring out of the boy's ear, as the earring is what was causing him to be a changeling. The showdown ends in the van driving through the wall of the parking garage.

The little boy is returned to his family and the book ends with the girl hearing giggling and finding that the little boy and his siblings left a gift for her.

I cannot for certain remember the names of any of the characters, but Jayme may have been the little boy's name. The main character's mom's name may have been something like Maureen, but not sure on either.

I read this when I was a young teen so I'd guess the book was published in the 80's or early 90's.

The cover art featured a girl (maybe with red hair), a little boy with an earring, and a guy with a penny whistle, sitting in the grass, and a castle can be seen in the background.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! For future reference, you need to hit Enter twice for a paragraph break, not once.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: The book is call Out of the Ordinary, by Annie Dalton